How do the LDS Church reconcile their teaching that the Lord withdrew the authority of the Priesthood from the earth with the book of Hebrews?

When individuals or groups of people turn away from the principles of the gospel, they are in a state of apostasy. One example is the Great Apostasy, which occurred after the Savior established His Church. After the deaths of the Savior and His Apostles, men corrupted the principles of the gospel and made unauthorized changes in Church organization and priesthood ordinances. Because of this widespread apostasy, the Lord withdrew the authority of the priesthood from the earth. This apostasy lasted until Heavenly Father and His Beloved Son appeared to Joseph Smith in 1820 and initiated the Restoration of the fulness of the gospel. ("Apostasy")

But Hebrews says

Hebrews 2:17: Therefore, He/Jesus Christ had to be made like His brethren in all things, that He might become a merciful and faithful high priest in things pertaining to God, to make propitiation for the sins of the people.


Hebrews 5:6: just as He says also in another passage, "Thou art a Priest forever according to the order of Melchizedek."


Hebrews 7:23-25: And the former priests, on the one hand, existed in greater numbers, because they were prevented by death from continuing. but He, on the other hand because He abides forever, holds His priesthood permanently. Hence, also, He is able to save forever those who draw near to God through Him, since He always lives to make intercession for them.

By His death and resurrection Jesus Christ secured the priesthood for sinners forever. His death provided a covering for sins.
In view of this on what basis can the LDS Church say the priesthood authority was withdrawn from the earth?

The only reconcilitation need I see is with your conclusion/interpretation "By His death and resurrection Jesus Christ secured the priesthood for sinners forever.". Still, I think the changes resolve the close reason. @curiousdannii Do you disagree? Should this question still be closed after the change or reopened?

Up-voted +1. This will also be relevant to those who suggest that priesthood (and even sacrifices I am informed) will be reinstated during a period of one thousand years. Good question.

Just to clarify, the LDS Church does not believe the Melchizedek priesthood has ever not been on the Earth. There has been a bearer of that priesthood on the planet every day since Adam. What was removed (as a consequence of apostasy, 2 Thes 2:3) was the ecclesiastical authority to establish and administer His church - the organization of the priesthood. We fully believe that Jesus is the great high priest of the Melchizedek priesthood and we have no problem with the book of Hebrews. In fact, we point to it as justification that it's required in the true church.

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints don't see any need of reconciliation with these verses.
The atonement covers sinners, but nothing related to priesthood per se

As used in the scriptures, to atone is to suffer the penalty for sins, thereby removing the effects of sin from the repentant sinner and allowing him or her to be reconciled to God. Jesus Christ was the only one capable of carrying out the Atonement for all mankind. Because of His Atonement, all people will be resurrected, and those who obey His gospel will receive the gift of eternal life with God.

Hebrews 2 is about the atonement, but doesn't say anything about reconciliation/securing the priesthood forever.
Hebrews 5 does say Christ held the Melchizedek Priesthood, but that priesthood can be held by anyone who is worthy. As the LDS believe in eternity, priesthood holders can hold it forever as well. This verse does not specify that Christ is the last to hold this power or the only one, the LDS believe the 12 apostles then (New Testament times) and now, hold the priesthood.
Hebrews 7:23-25 KJV (not JST) has slightly different wording that I believe changes the potential meaning:

23 And they truly were many priests, because they were not suffered to continue by reason of death:
24 But this man, because he continueth ever, hath an unchangeable priesthood.
25 Wherefore he is able also to save them to the uttermost that come unto God by him, seeing he ever liveth to make intercession for them.

So the basis on these verses doesn't do much to say the priesthood did/did not get withdrawn. These verses are just about Jesus Christ holding the Melchizedek priesthood performed the Atonement for us, sinners. We know Christ isn't on the earth anymore so even if we assumed only Christ had the priesthood, this would be just another argument for apostasy as the priesthood left the earth. We know other people can hold the Priesthood from other bible references (Heb 7:11, 1 Peter 2:5,9), so then the restoration would be another person gaining the priesthood, and LDS beliefs stand the same.

Is the "restored" priesthood of LDS of the line of Melchizedek or Aaron?

@MikeBorden yes, it has both: https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/aaronic-priesthood?lang=eng and link to Melchizedek in answer

And so when Hebrews details how the Aaronic priesthood was temporary and is over, is that yet another part of the Bible that was corrupted and needed to be fixed?

@MikeBorden I don't believe Hebrews says that, nor is it part of the original question, unless you believe one of the verses stated states that

@MikeBorden see this question which I believe addresses your point

You reference Hebrews 7:11 but 12 explains further what is meant by 11.

@MikeBorden my ref to 7:11 was just that others can hold the priesthood, the other question I reference doesn't ref any specific verse in Heb 7

The whole point of verse 11 is that the Levitical Priesthood (Aaron) couldn't get the job done and a non-Aaron Priest was needed.  Hence, the verse 12 change.  Others can hold the Aaronic Priesthood but what's the point?  It can't work because those priests are subject to death.  The Aaronic Priesthood is dis-annulled by Christ (7:18).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Peter Turner. My answer contained nothing but Scripture so how could it have been "contentious?" And yes, if I was reading an encyclopedia with this answer I would have given it two thumbs up. It's not only "cogent" but it's the truth. And btw, I thought we were allowed to answer one's own question?
